# Form in symfony not properly submitted with nav-tabs

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I have a huge form in my symfony (4) application. This form has a 3 level collection type.

> **Institution** > **Classes** (displayed as nav-items) > (display in nav-content) **Subjects**  > **Ressources** (display in subject dropdown-toggle div)

I had to "cut" the form manually in order to display each Classe inside a boostrap (4) nav-tabs. But for a reason that I ignore, some form Institution doesn't submit all input from the 2 lasts tabs.

And the name of all my inputs are corrects :

```
<input ... name="[instituion][...][classe][...][subject][...][ressource][...][name]" >
```

But if I move the last tab at the first position, the moved-tab is completely submit (but the "new last" isn't anymore)

Does symfony have restriction with the number of element from a collection type form ? What do I missing knowing it works on the majority of all the institution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the navtabs, but with the serveur configuration.

I had to increase **post_max_size** and **max_input_vars**.